# Two dimensional taylor expansion of arbitrary function

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, approximation

Consider the function dependent on the variables $N_t$ and $N_{t-1}$. Call the function $f$ so $f = f(N_t, N_{t-1})$. Now suppose we could write $N_t = N^*+n_t$ where $N^*$ is constant, and $n_t$ varying. Hence $f = f(N^* + n_t, N^*+n_{t-1})$. I want the taylor expansion of this now which of the following is correct?

$$f(n_t+N^*, n_{t-1}+N^*) = f(N^*, N^*) + n_tf_{n_t}(N^*, N^*) + n_{t-1}f_{n_{n-1}}(N^*, N^*) + \mathcal{O}(2).$$

or

$$f(n_t+N^*, n_{t-1}+N^*) = f(N^*, N^*) + n_tf_{N_t}(N^*, N^*) + n_{t-1}f_{N_{n-1}}(N^*, N^*) + \mathcal{O}(2).$$

Comment: strange notations. and why N* should the the name on left and right ? anyway for Nd Taylor, see wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables . Note that it is exactly as in 1D by replacing scalars by vector, and expending the derivatives relative to vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $f=f(x,y)$ we have
$$f(a+h_a,b+h_b)=f(a,b) + f_x(a,b)h_a + f_y(a,b)h_b + O(h_a^2+h_b^2)$$
In your case $h_a=n_t$ and $h_b=n_{t-1}$ and $a=b=N^*$, therefore

$$f(n_t+N^*, n_{t-1}+N^*) = f(N^*, N^*) + (n_t f_x(N^*, N^*) + n_{t-1}f_{y}(N^*, N^*) + \mathcal{O}(n_t^2+n_{t-1}^2).
$$
$f_x(N^*, N^*)$ is the partial derivative with respect to the first variable evaluated at $(x,y)=(N^*, N^*)$. Similarly about $f_y$.

Since the above a little bit confusing you try to write it in a more confusing way:)

$$f(a+h_a,b+h_b)=f(a,b) + (\nabla f)(a,b)\cdot (h_a,h_b) + O(\|(h_a,h_b)\|^2)$$

Here the $\cdot$ is a dot product between two vectors, vector (function) gradient $\nabla f$ (evaluated at $(a,b)$) and vector $\vec{\delta_h}=(h_x,h_y)$, in this example you have $h_x=h_a$ and $h_y=h_b$.

Comment: what is $x$ and $y$ in this case?

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are the first and the second argument.

Comment: They are kind of your $N_t$ and $N_{t-1}$ , but less confusing, i.e. the second option was correct except of argument in O. You should distinct between definition of the function and evaluation at specific value, this way it will be much more clear to you.